# PowerShell Get-AppVServerPackage behaves differently when executed in a remote session

Tags: powershell

Good Morning all,

i have a slight problem with the remote execution of the "Get-AppVServerPackage" PowerShell Applet.

We try to receive all the information available for all packages from a remote location.

When executing "Get-AppVServerPackage" on the AppV server, i get:
the information about the contained applications.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIx4m.png

When i user Enter-PSSession from a PowerShell command line, i get

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvEtc.png

When i try to use it in a script supposed to run unattended, i get

[3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Ddf.png

So i tried to get more information about "Microsoft.AppV.Server.AppVMgmtDataTypes.Application"

```
$s = New-PSSession -computerName myAppVServer -Authentication Kerberos

$test = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Get-AppVServerPackage }

$test.Applications[0] |gm
```

will give me a long list of Methods, and only one Property "Length".

Can anyone tell me how i can get the information about the application? It works with the

```
$test.Entitlements
```

will give me a result i can work with.

Thanks a lot!
Holger

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you get lucky,

replacing

```
{ Get-AppVServerPackage }
```

with

```
{ Get-AppVServerPackage | Select ID, Name, Description, PackageGuid, VersionGuid, Applications, Entitlements }
```

solved the problem.